# Creating table with tinyInt primary key converts column to int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following script to generate a table (via SSMS). When I run the script then check the design of the table in SSMS the PK is an int when I defined it as a tinyint. Nothing I've found suggests this cannot be a tinyint.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DraftStatuses
    (
    DS_ID tinyint NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    DS_Name nvarchar(20) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.DraftStatuses ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_DraftStatuses PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    DS_ID
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9f2896409b9eb8b516d7e956b5e8dbee) this.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried this and the datatype of DS_ID did NOT change. But I would be wary of using a tinyint and an identity because the values can jump significantly on a server restart. Not sure what kind of havoc that would reap on a tinyint.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. Copied the code from the question into SSMS and hit F5. Then opened the visual designer - shows the DS_ID column as tinyint.

Comment: Same here. Remains tinyint. OP, what version of SQL Server is this in?

Comment: I'm going to close this. It was SSMS bugging out. I had deleted a previous version of the table and then re-run the script and it was still remembering old values for the table. Rebooting SSMS solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Someone may run into this and find this answer useful and save some of their time.

The problem was that I had deleted a table from SSMS and then run the script above to recreate it with some changes and SSMS remembered the old values when I checked the table design view.

The solution was to delete the table, reboot SSMS and run the script again.

Comment: And the moral of the story is: [Don't use the visual designers.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers)